# List box default text seems different size from drop down list text

Tags: css

Please take a look at [this very short example](http://jsfiddle.net/mawg/DSasp/1/)

```css
fieldset, legend, .TLabel, .TComboBox, .select, .select_option {
  font: 10px Arial;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="TComboBox">
  <select name="ComboBox1">
    <option class="select_option" selected value="Option">Option</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="TLabel">Label</div>
```

It's a subset of a real webpage and its CSS,  where the user says that thet the drop down list box text is of a different font to the rest of the text on the page.

Looking at the code, the fonts are the same, but looking at it visualy, I see what he means.  The default text of the list box seems larger - but if we click to see the list then the text of the list items seems smaller.

Is this a browser rendering issue or is there a CSS selector which I forgot about for that default entry of the drop down list box?

Comment: The question starts "Please take a look at this very short example" (and I accepted an answer three years ago :-)

Comment: Upvote for Lolx :-)  "links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code" - that's new :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set class attribute of `<select/>` tag.

`<select name="ComboBox1" class="TComboBox">`

Comment: +1 and the answer. Yay!!   This all started when I was very new to CSS and wasn't sure whether to put the classs on the DIV or on the control (still amn't too clear, actually ... )

Answer (score 1):

just put this,

```
fieldset,  legend, .input_text, .input_integer, .input_float, .input_mandatory,  .input_invalid, .input_warning, .TLabel, .TCheckBox, .TListBox,  .TComboBox, .TPanel, .TGroupBox, .TRadioGroup, .TextEditBox,  .TDatePicker, .datePicker, .TDatePicker_container,  .datePicker_container, .radio_button, .select, .select_option {
    font: 10px Arial;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```